# Unable to find local grunt on ubuntu

Tags: gruntjs, ubuntu-16.04, fatal-error, grunt-cli

I installed grunt globally by running the following commands

```
npm install grunt grunt-cli -g
```

And I also installed grunt and other project dependencies locally to my project by running

```
npm install
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

But grunt keeps telling me "Unable to find local grunt"

I'm Using ubuntu 16.04 on DigitalOcean and I have nodejs and npm installed
what is the problem?

Comment: Run `echo $PATH` and post the output please.

Comment: Actually I fixed the problem by downloading the project again from git, apparently it was corrupted.. thanks!